# How to make Jersey 2 Client to handle cookies on redirect

Tags: java, redirect, cookies, jersey-2.0

My application has a resource that sets a Cookie and the sends a redirect. The destination of the redirect requires the cookie to be set.

When calling the resource in e. g. Chrome, it works fine. 
But when I use Jersey 2 Client to call a resource, it follows the redirect, but the cookie is not set.

Is there a way to make Jersey handle cookies like a browser?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Jersey 2 Client and the only solution for me was to set `ClientProperties.FOLLOW_REDIRECTS` to `false` and handle the redirect separately.

```
clientConfig.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, false);
```